# Play Slick database error - table definition class

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I have problem with creating a table definition class with Play Slick. Here is my class:

```
package database;

class EmployeeTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[Employee](tag, "employee_data") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def resume = column[String]("resume")
  def additionalInformation = column[String]("additionalInformation")

  override def * =
    (id, name, resume, additionalInformation) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

It's simple and I did it according to the tutorial(http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/). However I'm getting strange error:
Compilation error. `{' expected but`(' found. EmployeeTableDef.java:3

and it displays that there is a problem with (tag:Tag) part. I would be grateful for your help!

Btw I am using slick 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong file extension. It's `EmployeeTableDef.scala`

Comment: OMG... so obvious but I didn't saw it. Thanks a lot!